# inner join on PK with extra criteria slow despite indices?

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, join, query-performance

Given the two tables below I am struggling to understand:

- why is the third query slow even though first two queries are fast
- what exactly is EXPLAIN saying
- can I do anything to significantly speed up the slow query?

joining two tables on PK is fast:

```
mysql> select sql_no_cache p.id, sv.postProcessed 
       from product_views p, site_visits sv 
       where p.siteVisitId=sv.id 
       limit 1;
+----+---------------+
| id | postProcessed |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |             1 |
+----+---------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

so is just selecting PVs by timestamp range:

```sql
mysql> select sql_no_cache p.id, p.timestamp 
       from product_views p 
       where p.timestamp >= "2012-10-10" 
         and p.timestamp < "2012-11-10" 
       limit 1;
+-----------+---------------------+
| id        | timestamp           |
+-----------+---------------------+
| 501719231 | 2012-10-10 00:01:03 |
+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.56 sec)
```

**but joining the two is really slow** (takes 5 min+ ):

```sql
mysql> select sql_no_cache p.id, p.timestamp, sv.postProcessed 
       from product_views p, site_visits sv 
       where p.siteVisitId=sv.id 
         and p.timestamp >= "2012-10-10" 
         and p.timestamp < "2012-11-10" 
       limit 1;
```

here's the EXPLAIN

```
mysql> explain select sql_no_cache p.id, p.timestamp, sv.postProcessed from product_views p, site_visits sv where p.siteVisitId=sv.id and p.timestamp >= "2012-10-10" and p.timestamp < "2012-11-10" limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                              | key                | key_len | ref                 | rows      | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | index  | FK52C29B1E3CAB9CC4,timestamp_idx,siteVisitId_timestamp_idx | FK52C29B1E3CAB9CC4 | 8       | NULL                | 119195469 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sv    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                    | PRIMARY            | 8       | clabs.p.siteVisitId |         1 |                          |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

**Questions**

- i was expecting the last query to run approx as quickly as the first 2 added together:  1) identify a product_view within given timestamp and 2) do a constant lookup on matching site_visit row. There are < 95m rows in product_views within that timestamp range, not sure why 120M are being scanned...
- the explain above seems to say that 'timestamp_idx' wasn't used. why not? (I guess mysqld is doing a full partition scan for product_views matching by timestamp)
- i tried adding a (siteVisitId, timestamp) index to cover all properties used in 'WHERE' - but that's not getting used either. Why?
- what can I do to speed things up?

**Notes on our db:**

- both tables are 100M+ rows
- every product_view has an exactly one siteVisit. (FK was removed to accomodate InnoDB partitioning constraints)
- using mysql 5.5
- no other traffic against db server

**TABLES**

```
mysql> show create table site_visits\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: site_visits
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `site_visits` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postProcessed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `siteVisitState` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `post_processed_idx` (`postProcessed`),
  KEY `visit_state_idx` (`siteVisitState`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


mysql> show create table product_views\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: product_views
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `product_views` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `FK52C29B1E3CAB9CC4` (`siteVisitId`),
  KEY `rebateSearchZipCode_idx` (`rebateSearchZipCode`),
  KEY `siteVisitId_timestamp_idx` (`siteVisitId`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `timestamp_idx` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(`timestamp`)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-05-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-06-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-08-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
/* partition declarations truncated */
 PARTITION p33 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Comment: Please provide EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...;

Comment: KEY `timestamp_idx` (`timestamp`) --> KEY `timestamp_idx` (`timestamp`, siteVisitId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer does not see that your conditions are correlated and picks the wrong access method.

Basically, it considers two options:

1. Scan the index on `siteVisitId` until the first match on `site_visits` and the first satisfied `timestamp` condition.
2. Scan the index on `timestamp` until the first match on `site_visits`.

Since `timestamp` is a part of the primary key and `siteVisitId` is not, the second plan would involve table lookups on `product_views` which is several times more slow than a pure index scan (note `Using index` in the plan).

The optimizer calculates the conditional probability of the `timestamp` condition being satisfied (given that a corresponding `site_visit` record exists) and compares it to the overhead of the table access.

Since your `timestamp` condition is quite wide (as seen on the index histograms), the optimizer prefers the first method.

However, since both `siteVisitId` and `timestamp` are incremental, they are correlated and the conditional probability of both matches is not a mere product of their independent probabilities.

In simple words, you have to filter through many low `siteVisitId` until you find the first matching `timestamp`, which is exactly what is happening to your query.

You should add `ORDER BY timestamp` to your query to make the `timestamp` index cheaper as it won't have to sort. It would also help to create an index on `timestamp, siteVisitId` (in this order) to avoid table lookups.

Comment: excellent answer - thank you! the explanation makes sense, adding suggested index cut the above query time to < 1s.